# Styling A Navbar Button With Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a link to test page:
http://goo.gl/J8bS8P

I'm trying to get the navbar button to have the same styles as the basic button.

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Service Area</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Basic Button</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" href="#contact">Navbar Button</a>
                </li><!--                   
                <li>
                    <a class="navbar-btn button-id-1" href="tel:713-992-0916" style="padding:2px;background-color:rgba(174,20,42,0.5    )">
                Click to Call <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"></span>713-992-0916
                    </a>
                </li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I thought that styling the button would be as easy as copying the basic buttons stylings and making a new class for navbar button, as so...

```
.navbar-btn {
    border-color: #ae142a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ae142a;
}


.btn-primary {
    border-color: #ae142a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ae142a;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
.navbar-btn {
    border-color: #ae142a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ae142a;
    padding: 6px 12px !important;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.navbar-btn:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #337AB7 !important;
    border-color: #2E6DA4 !important;
}

.btn-primary {
    border-color: #ae142a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="hidden">
            <a href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Service Area</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Basic Button</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" href="#contact">Navbar Button</a>
        </li><!--                   
        <li>
            <a class="navbar-btn button-id-1" href="tel:713-992-0916" style="padding:2px;background-color:rgba(174,20,42,0.5    )">
        Click to Call <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"></span>713-992-0916
            </a>
        </li>-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59g2q1q1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's almost as easy as copying and pasting - you need to add `!important` to all the styles for the navbar button. Also, if you don't want such a poofy button, adjust the padding. And remember, every style you put in, make sure to type `!important` because there are so many styles that overwrite it!

```
.navbar-btn {
   border-color: #ae142a !important;
   text-transform: uppercase !important;
   font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
   font-weight: 700;
   color: #fff !important;
   background-color: #ae142a !important;

   padding: 8px 10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should basically be the same across all states.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 50px;
}
/*Start Navbar Button*/

.btn.navbar-btn {
  border-color: #ae142a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ae142a;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px !important;
}
.btn.navbar-btn:hover,
.btn.navbar-btn:focus,
.btn.navbar-btn.focus,
.btn.navbar-btn:active,
.btn.navbar-btn.active,
.btn.open .dropdown-toggle.navbar-btn {
  border-color: #1f344d!important;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1f344d !important;
  text-decoration: none
}
.btn.navbar-btn:active,
.btn.navbar-btn.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn.navbar-btn,
.btn.navbar-btn:active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)
}
.btn.navbar-btn.disabled,
.btn.navbar-btn[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn.navbar-btn,
.btn.navbar-btn.disabled:hover,
.btn.navbar-btn[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-btn:hover,
.navbar-btn.disabled:focus,
.navbar-btn[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn.navbar-btn:focus,
.btn.navbar-btn.disabled:active,
.btn.navbar-btn[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn.navbar-btn:active,
.btn.navbar-btn.disabled.active,
.btn.navbar-btn[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-btn.active {
  border-color: #fed136 !important;
  background-color: #fed136 !important;
}
.btn.navbar-btn .badge {
  color: #fed136;
  background-color: #fff;
}
/*Start Primary*/

.btn.btn-primary {
  border-color: #ae142a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ae142a;
}
.btn.btn-primary:hover,
.btn.btn-primary:focus,
.btn.btn-primary:active,
.btn.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn.btn-primary {
  border-color: #1f344d;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1f344d;
}
.btn.btn-primary:active,
.btn.btn-primary.active,
.btn.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn.btn-primary[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn.btn-primary,
.btn.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn.btn-primary:hover,
.btn.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn.btn-primary:focus,
.btn.btn-primary.disabled:active,
.btn.btn-primary[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn.btn-primary:active,
.btn.btn-primary.disabled.active,
.btn.btn-primary[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn.btn-primary.active {
  border-color: #fed136;
  background-color: #fed136;
}
.btn.btn-primary .badge {
  color: #fed136;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Basic Button</button>
<a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" href="#contact">Basic Button </a>
```